# Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Installation Error - 'Wait on the Database Engine Recovery Handle Failed'

Tags: sql-server, authentication, server, installation, account

[image]I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition on my Windows 10 Operating System today.

I got the error:  **Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.**

I am not able to enable my SQL Server Database Engine  (Log on as:    NT Service\MSSQL$SQL2016DEV).

I am using a built-in administrator account in my laptop;

UserName:    MachineName\Administrator

I read through some online forums I need to change this to NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE or
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.

Interestingly, some other features  are successful in my installation. One of them is Analysis Service Engine.

What will be the best solution for me?  In my machine I already have SQL Server 2012,2008R2,2005installed (all Developer Editions) running various applications;

SQL Server 2012 Database Engine has NT Service\MSSQL$SQL2012DEV

SQL Server 20108R2 Database Engine has NT AUTHORITY\Network Service

SQL Server 2005 Database Engine has Local System

I cannot uninstall any of the above 3 versions (all the above 3 are fine still).

Thanks.

Comment: Can I change 'Log on as'  to   Built-in account    from 'This Account'  as shown in the picture?  Then restart. Will that work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with built in - Local account. This error happens when the account in question, does no have sufficient privileges.

Comment: Please explain in which way this will increase which kind of privileges over those of an admin account, which OP states to use.